# React Native run - Android producing strange error

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'd like to ask about the following error. So I've been developing a small BLE app a year ago and successfully managed to implement it. I did not push it to the Google Play store but instead installed it somehow on the Android via usb.

However, now I need to get it back up and running but am facing a plethora of errors.

```
PS C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard> npx react-native run-android 
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1302 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
 unimodules-core@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\@unimodules\core
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter
 expo-app-loader-provider@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-app-loader-provider
 expo-constants@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-constants
 expo-error-recovery@1.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-error-recovery
 expo-file-system@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-file-system
 expo-font@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-font
 expo-keep-awake@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-keep-awake
 expo-linear-gradient@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-linear-gradient
 expo-location@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-location
 expo-permissions@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-permissions
 expo-sqlite@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-sqlite
 expo-web-browser@8.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\expo-web-browser
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-camera-interface
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-constants-interface
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-face-detector-interface
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-file-system-interface
 unimodules-font-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-font-interface
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-image-loader-interface
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-permissions-interface
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.0.0 from C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard\node_modules\unimodules-task-manager-interface

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo-error-recovery', ':expo-permissions'

> Task :@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
10 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 9 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251 contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

PS C:\Users\stefanec\Desktop\SOC\i_garden\i_garden\iGard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have JDK installed.

Use the command below to install it with brew if you're on a Mac or follow the docs to how to install on your specific machine

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

Follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/react-native-tips-setting-up-your-development-environment-for-windows-d326635604ea) to install on windows

See docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/_getting-started-macos-android#installing-dependencies

Comment: fortunee , THANK YOU SO MUCH! I didn't have the slightest clue that not having jdk could be the problem, especially when I vividly remember installing it at some point. 

Nevertheless, your solution is 100% correct and you have more than certainly saved me lots of hours!

Could I ask you how did you find that out?

It's not mentioned anywhere. The error even points out react library or deprecated Gradle, but no mention of jdk missing.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked. Basically did some googling and narrowed it down.